# How to merge subsequent values of specific column in table in r

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge repetitive row with a specific content only.

let say I have following datafram

```
df:
user action
1     A
1     A
1     B
1     B
2     A
2     C
2     C
2     A
2     A
```

I want to merge only subsequent action `A` only.
so the result would be:

```
user action
1     A
1     B
1     B
2     A
2     C
2     C
2     A
```

how can I do it in R?
thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as there are no other conditions to match, this will work with:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
```

Start by creating a dummy column that tells us whether it's an immediate duplicate of the prior "A":

```
> df %>% group_by(user) %>% 
    mutate(condition=paste0(action,lag(action)==action)) 
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   user [2]
  user  action condition
  <fct> <fct>  <chr>    
1 1     A      ANA      
2 1     A      ATRUE    
3 1     B      BFALSE   
4 1     B      BTRUE    
5 2     A      ANA      
6 2     C      CFALSE   
7 2     C      CTRUE    
8 2     A      AFALSE   
9 2     A      ATRUE
```

Then you can filter out the rows within each user where A follows another A:

```
> df %>% group_by(user) %>% 
    mutate(condition=paste0(action,lag(action)==action)) %>% 
    filter(condition!="ATRUE") 
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   user [2]
  user  action condition
  <fct> <fct>  <chr>    
1 1     A      ANA      
2 1     B      BFALSE   
3 1     B      BTRUE    
4 2     A      ANA      
5 2     C      CFALSE   
6 2     C      CTRUE    
7 2     A      AFALSE
```

You don't even have to reveal the dummy column because you can just filter out the rows that match "ATRUE" and then select the two variables you care about:

```
> df %>% group_by(user) %>% 
    mutate(condition=paste0(action,lag(action)==action)) %>% 
    filter(condition!="ATRUE") %>% select(user,action)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   user [2]
  user  action
  <fct> <fct> 
1 1     A     
2 1     B     
3 1     B     
4 2     A     
5 2     C     
6 2     C     
7 2     A
```